# How to calculate the overall accuracy of a system with two sequential steps (two classifiers)?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification

**How to calculate the overall accuracy of a system with two sequential steps (two classifiers)?** In my scenario, I calculate the `accuracy` results for each step separately and then combine the overall results. For example, let's assume that I want to predict 1000 data instances in the first step and that the first classifier was able to predict 700 samples correctly (70% `accuracy`).

In the second step, I try to predict the other 300 data instances (that weren't predicted in the first step). So, if the second classifier was able to predict 150 data instances, this gives us an `accuracy` of 50% for the second step (Second classifier). So, How Should I calculate my overall accuracy of both steps?

Comment: This system to me seems quite confusing. How do you know which samples have been correctly classified in the first step, to then pass on the misclassified ones?

Comment: @LaksanNathan TP and TN are the correctly classified instances by the first classifier. Therefore, I try to predict the FP and FN of the first classifier (300 in my example) using the second classifier.

Comment: You probably want to predict unseen instances after training. Your first classifier gives you predictions. How do you know TP,TN and FP,FN for unseen data?

Comment: @LaksanNathan once I predict the test set (1000 instance) I compare them with the true label and use a confusion matrix to get (TP, TN, FP and FN) I hope I got your question right.

Comment: Let's imagine your system is deployed to predict the class of entirely new examples (for which you don't know the true class). This after all is the goal of developing a model. Can you explain how the second step is triggered in this case?

Comment: @dipetkov what I done is after I get the predictions of the first classifier I train the second classifier on the TP and TN (700 data instances correctly classified) of the first classifier and try to predict the FP and FN of the first classifier (the 300 instances) using the second classifier

Comment: Unfortunately, and this is what @Laksan Nathan also points out, is that in real life you don't know whether the first classifier got it right or wrong (unless you decide to label more data). What you propose cannot be done in a practical way.

Comment: @dipetkov could you explain this further. Still not clear to me. I would like to mention that I used unsupervised classifier in the first step

Comment: It doesn't matter what classifier you used in the first step. To know whether the prediction is a TF, FN, etc., you need to know the true label. You only know the true label while you are training the model. In a "production setting" you simply don't know the label (that's why you need a classifier!) Please read the comments. You are focusing on how to evaluate your system; while the comments try to explain why your system doesn't make sense in the first place.